# Why isn't Jenkins running all of my TestNG tests?

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

If I run a collection of test classes in IntelliJ, 246 tests run with a TestNG run configuration. I just hooked this project up to Jenkins and for some reason Jenkins is only running 75 tests.

This is how 99% of these tests are organized:

```
package serviceLayer.styx.qa.endpoints;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(groups = {"serviceLayer.qa.endpoints"})
public class ExampleTest extends ExampleTestBase {

  @Test
  public void stackOverflowExample() {
    // test something
  }
}
```

Here is the shell command I'm running via Jenkins:

> cd "${WORKSPACE}" && mvn -fae -Duser=qa clean -Dtest=serviceLayer.qa.endpoints.* test surefire-report:report

So far I've tried adding groups tags to each test class and changed the Jenkins job from a pipeline job to whatever the opposite is ... but only 75 tests continue to run.

Note: Jenkins is not ignoring the tests, its like they're simply not getting recognized.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: How are you starting the tests from Jenkins? Show the pipeline and standalone job code (or mvn command line + pom snippet, or whatever)

Comment: @PaulHicks added, thank you

Comment: You are running your tests using IntelliJ. What happened when you run the same `mvn -fae ...` command line in your own computer?

Comment: You said "shell command".. have you been running this on Windows yourself, and on Linux via Jenkins? Because.. globbing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Jenkins is running maven on a Linux node. Which means it's using sh or bash to parse your command line. Which means your line is being globbed before it's being run. Presumably you don't have any files matching the glob pattern `-Dtest=serviceLayer.qa.endpoints.*`, so that expands to the the empty string. So your maven command line being run is

```
mvn -fae -Duser=qa clean test surefire-report:report
```

And presumably 75 tests will run with that command line, but the others require the test definition.

Try escaping or quoting the asterisk in the command line.

```
cd "${WORKSPACE}" && mvn -fae -Duser=qa clean -Dtest=serviceLayer.qa.endpoints.\* test surefire-report:report
```